# Change the color of text according to the background

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

In notification the label color is based on the background. Such type of effect i want.

[image: Effect in iPhone]

I need help in selecting the color of the label or section index based on the background of the label.

[image: Section index colorful]

[image: Section index single color]

This is how i want the label/ index to look like.
I was able to set single color for text.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe a white and translucent (e.g. alpha 50%) color for the letters...?

Comment: If i set alpha than it shows the color of background but its not bright. The background is blur and the index is not.

Comment: It's a visual effects view with vibrancy effect.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
test.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title_bg"]];
```

Comment: Thats not how i want it. It gives a static effect. but i want that label should change color with the background

Comment: @iOSDeveloper asking people to code everything for you from ground up is not what SO is about. Instead you should update your question with methods and code you've already tried so you can receive more specific answers

Comment: @soulshined thanks, I am still learning how to write a good question. I will add my code as well. But like Desdenova said i will have to use vibrancy effect. Is what i want.